# URL rewriting in Servlet/JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I know that `response.sendRedirect()` destroys the request/response object and new request is sent to the resource. So how come `request.getParameter("")` fetches me the value if the earlier request/response object has already been destroyed.

NewFile.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action ="MyServlet">
<label>Username</label>
<input type="text" name="textbox1"/><br>
<label>Password</label><input type="password" name="textbox2"/>
<input type="submit"/>    
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Servlet

```
/**
 * Servlet implementation class MyServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/MyServlet")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String user = request.getParameter("textbox1");
String password = request.getParameter("textbox2");
if (user.equals("abc")&&password.equals("123"))
{
response.sendRedirect("NewFile.jsp?name="+user);
}
    }

        }
```

Newfile.jsp

```
<%= "hi there"+request.getParameter("name")  %>
```

Comment: If you are talking about your jsp getting parameter "name"... it's simply because you have put the request directly in the url (NewFile.jsp?name=xuser). If not, I didn't understand your question, please try to be clearer

Comment: yes I am.Okay understood. The response is sent back to the client and new request is sent to jsp which already has parameters.

Comment: In case the problem is solved, please remove the question or add an answer (and accept that).

Comment: I have added my initial comment as an answer. Plz Sanjana, mark it as solution! Hope you enjoy Servlets :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I repeated here the comment so you can mark your question as solved by this answer :D

If you are talking about your jsp getting parameter "name"... it's simply because you have put the request directly in the url (NewFile.jsp?name=xuser). If not, I didn't understand your question, please try to be clearer

Answer (score 0):

It is because at very first request, you are getting the parameter, after that you are sending redirect response, if you will do same thing on redirected page or servlet, you will not able to get any thing. In your case, you are sending parameter name with value, so you will be able to get it.

Answer (score -1):

Go to your "NewFile.jsp" page, in that page `<%=request.getParameter("name")>.`
It will simply get the value you passed in `URL("NewFile.jsp?name="+user).`